# Cross validation in thiessen polygons interpolation

Tags: r, voronoi-thiessen, cross-validation

I apply Thiessen Polygons interpolation using the krige command in the gstat R package. Using `krige` without a variogram model sets automatically krige function to perform IDW, and when nmax parameter is set to 1, it is actually performing thiessen polygons interpolation.
What I have is this:

```
dec_vor = krige(Dec ~ 1, st, grd, nmax = 1)
```

Then, when I want to perform cross validation, i do this:

```
dec_vor_cv = krige.cv(Dec ~ 1, st, nfold = 52, dec_vor)
```

and I get this error message:

```
"Error in load.variogram.model(object$model[[name]], c(i - 1, i - 1)) : 
  model should be of mode variogramModel (use function vgm)"
```

Comment: (perhaps better known as 'nearest neighbor' interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not be directly apparent from the documentation, the third (unnamed) argument to your `krige.cv` call is assumed to be a variogram model, and is absorbed by the argument `model`. Since `dec_vor` is the outcome of a call to `krige`, it is not, hence the error message.

It is not clear to me why you would pass `dec_vor` to `krige.cv`, as `krige.cv` loops over the observations in `st` only, nothing else.

Comment: thank you for your response! When I do not pass dec_vor  to krige.cv, the command works fine. The reason why I wanted to to pass dec_vor to krige.cv is because I wanted krige.cv to evaluate dev_vor. Is this wrong?

Comment: then you should replace `st` with `dev_vor`; this will however depending on the density of `grd` nearly certainly give perfect results that have nothing to do with how good interpolation of `st` went.